React Beautiful DnD: Unable to Drop Songs into Folders After Fetching Data
I'm working on a React application using react-beautiful-dnd to implement drag-and-drop functionality for songs and folders. The drag-and-drop works perfectly with locally created folders, but I'm encountering issues when trying to drop songs into folders that are fetched from the backend. After fetching, the folders become undroppable, and there's no hover effect.
Here's a simplified version of my setup:
CatalogComponent.tsx
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { DragDropContext, DropResult } from 'react-beautiful-dnd'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchCatalog, fetchFolders } from './catalogSlice'
import { unwrapResult } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'
import CatalogFolder from './CatalogFolder'
import SongList from './SongList'
import { Folder, Song } from '../../../app/layout/models/catalog'
import { createStandardFolder, getFolderDroppableId } from '../../../app/layout/utils/folderUtils'

export default function CatalogComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [localCatalog, setLocalCatalog] = useState<{ songs: Song[] } | null>(null)
  const [localFolders, setLocalFolders] = useState<Folder[]>([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true)
      try {
        const [catalogResult, foldersResult] = await Promise.all([
          dispatch(fetchCatalog()),
          dispatch(fetchFolders()),
        ])

        const catalogData = unwrapResult(catalogResult)
        const foldersData = unwrapResult(foldersResult)

        const standardizedFolders = foldersData.map(createStandardFolder)
        setLocalCatalog(catalogData)
        setLocalFolders(standardizedFolders)
      } catch (error) {
        toast.error('Error fetching data')
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false)
      }
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [dispatch])

  const handleDragEnd = useCallback((result: DropResult) => {
    if (!result.destination) return

    const { source, destination, draggableId } = result

    if (source.droppableId === 'song-list' && destination.droppableId.startsWith('folder-')) {
      const folderId = parseInt(destination.droppableId.split('-')[1], 10)
      const songId = parseInt(draggableId, 10)

      const song = localCatalog?.songs.find(s => s.songId === songId)
      if (!song) return

      setLocalFolders(prevFolders => {
        return prevFolders.map(folder => {
          if (folder.id === folderId) {
            return {
              ...folder,
              nodes: [...folder.nodes, { id: Date.now(), songId: song.songId, name: song.name, nodes: [] }]
            }
          }
          return folder
        })
      })
    }
  }, [localCatalog])

  if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>

  return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
      <CatalogFolder folders={localFolders} />
      <SongList songs={localCatalog?.songs || []} />
    </DragDropContext>
  )
}

CatalogFolder.tsx
import React from 'react'
import { Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd'
import { Folder } from '../../../app/layout/models/catalog'

interface Props {
  folders: Folder[]
}

const CatalogFolder: React.FC<Props> = ({ folders }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {folders.map(folder => (
        <Droppable key={folder.id} droppableId={`folder-${folder.id}`}>
          {(provided, snapshot) => (
            <div
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              style={{
                background: snapshot.isDraggingOver ? 'lightblue' : 'lightgrey',
                padding: 4,
                width: 250,
                minHeight: 500,
              }}
            >
              <h4>{folder.name}</h4>
              {provided.placeholder}
            </div>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default CatalogFolder

Problem:

Issue: After fetching folders from the backend, I can't drop songs
into them. The hover effect doesn't appear, indicating that the
droppable area isn't being recognized.
Expected Behavior: Songs should be draggable into any folder, and the
folder should highlight when a song is dragged over it.

What I've Tried:

Ensured that droppableId is correctly set for each folder.
Verified that the DragDropContext and Droppable components are
correctly implemented.
Checked that the folders are correctly fetched and standardized.

Question:
What could be causing the fetched folders to become undroppable, and how can I resolve this issue?

I found the solution to my problem with the drag-and-drop functionality in React 18. The issue was related to the use of Droppable from react-beautiful-dnd. In React 18, it's recommended to use a custom StrictModeDroppable component to handle the strict mode rendering behavior.
Here's the custom StrictModeDroppable component I used:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Droppable, DroppableProps } from 'react-beautiful-dnd'

export const StrictModeDroppable: React.FC<DroppableProps> = ({
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const animation = requestAnimationFrame(() => setEnabled(true))

    return () => {
      cancelAnimationFrame(animation)
      setEnabled(false)
    }
  }, [])

  if (!enabled) {
    return null
  }

  return <Droppable {...props}>{children}</Droppable>
}

How It Works:

Strict Mode Compatibility: React 18's strict mode can cause
components to mount and unmount multiple times. This custom component
uses requestAnimationFrame to delay the rendering of the Droppable
until after the initial mount, preventing issues with the
drag-and-drop context.
State Management: The enabled state ensures    that the Droppable is
only rendered after the component is stable.

Implementation:
I've replace the standard Droppable with StrictModeDroppable in my component:
import { StrictModeDroppable } from './path/to/StrictModeDroppable'

// Usage in CatalogFolder component
<StrictModeDroppable droppableId={`folder-${folder.id}`}>
  {(provided, snapshot) => (
    <div
      ref={provided.innerRef}
      {...provided.droppableProps}
      style={{
        background: snapshot.isDraggingOver ? 'lightblue' : 'lightgrey',
        padding: 4,
        width: 250,
        minHeight: 500,
      }}
    >
      <h4>{folder.name}</h4>
      {provided.placeholder}
    </div>
  )}
</StrictModeDroppable>

Conclusion:
By using StrictModeDroppable, I was able to resolve the issue with dropping songs into folders after fetching them from the backend. This approach ensures compatibility with React 18's strict mode and maintains the expected drag-and-drop functionality.
I hope this helps others facing similar issues!
